# can not solve inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

In a few days I have tested and I can not seem to solve the following exercises:

[image: Picture of exercises]

thank you.

Comment: Log them, and never stop logging

Comment: Recall that $\log (x^b)=b\log (x) $. You can exploit this fact

Comment: For the third one: multiply both sides by $3$ and use more or less the same trick that you saw me do in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do one of them, as it turns out, because all the bases are the same, you want to use this, in the following way:

$$6^{\sqrt{x+3}}>6 (6^x) \implies 6^{\sqrt{x+3}}>6^{x+1} \implies \sqrt {x+3}>x+1. $$

You should be able to finish this. The real reason you can use the last implication is that the exponential function is one to one! For example, if you pick a $y $ value on the graph, say $y=3$, there is only one $x $ that satisfies $b^x=3$! So if $b^x=b^y $, then $x=y $. Furthermore, $b^x$ and its inverse are increasing functions, so it preserves order relations. Therefore, you should aim to get two things with the same base.

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that both $x\mapsto b^x$ and $b^x\mapsto x$ are increasing, so it is indeed valid to move between these forms to solve the inequalities, since ordering is preserved by increasing maps.

Comment: @Glare first things first, change the equalities to $>$! Thank you, edited